# CORS error on Django S3 Direct

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using Django S3 Direct to upload files to an S3 Bucket

I use the following configs

```
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = ''
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = ''
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = ''
```

The values for these were generated in the IAM Management console

I setup the bucket and the CORS configuration is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

However, when I try to upload a file in the Django admin, it gives me the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://s3.amazonaws.com/<bucketname>. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, except that I keep gettings 301 from AWS. After some digging I found this comment [comment](https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class/issues/46#issuecomment-18100537):

> From what I know, S3 is cross-region, which means that you do not need
>   to specify a region to upload files to, as it will uploads to one and
>   replicates to other regions behind the scenes. Therefor endpoint =
>   's3.amazonaws.com' If your bucket called 'test', you will upload to
>   'test.s3.amazonaws.com', not to 'test.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'.

So I solve this doing the opposite of what @Kanhaiya suggested. I had `S3DIRECT_REGION` in the `settings` and after removing it (to query `s3.amazonaws.com` directly) things get fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with django-s3direct even after adding CORS values as you mentioned. For me the problem was resolved after added the
S3DIRECT_REGION = 'ap-southeast-1'
you can choose your region from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region)